# Open and close websites in batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to make an batch file that opens a website for 5 seconds, then closes it an then loop the batch,  I got not much Succes, does anyone now how to do this, without letting all te cmd pages on screen(so the batch also closes the cmd after running)  I hope someone can help me.

this is the code i got so far, it works but it doesnt close the cmd.exe (Web is the name of the .bat file)

```
@echo off 
start "chrome.exe" "http://www.websitehere. co" 
timeout /t 3
taskkill /IM chrome.exe /F
:loop
start /wait Web
goto loop
```

Greetz Bas

Comment: Please post up what you've tried, people will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this code, hope it's good for you:

What i've done is do a while loop, for you to choose how many times will the loop run.

I set the timeout as 10 seconds but you can change it for 5 seconds.

```
@echo off
set /A x=0
:while
if %x% LEQ 2 (
    echo %x%
    start /max chrome.exe https://www.google.es
    timeout 10
    taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe > null
        set /A x=%x%+1
    goto :while
)
```